# vb.net how to show data from sql in lable

Tags: sql, vb.net

i want show my select syntac into lable but my code no work this only show 1 actualy data is 11

```
Try
    If IsNothing(ds.Tables("kkpsurabaya")) = False Then
        ds.Tables("kkpsurabaya").Rows.Clear()
    End If

    query = "SELECT count(total_telat) FROM kkpsurabaya WHERE LATE <=30 And Late >=1"

    da = New SqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "kkpsurabaya")

    Label7.Text = da.Fill(ds, "kkpsurabaya")

    da.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    FatalErrorOccured(ex)
End Try
```

[image: pic1]

[image]

Comment: Is that there are 2 fields : "LATE" and "Late" or just typo?

Comment: just typo but that work in sql

Comment: `Label7.Text` will show number of returned rows? If you want to show sql query in label then use `Label9.Text = query`

Comment: no work man that show my syntax in lable like "select * from " no point what i want.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a data adapter and `DataTable` for this.  That's for getting a tabular result set.  If you want a single value then use a command and call `ExecuteScalar`.

```
Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, conn)

Label7.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
```

To learn what ADO.NET objects to use in what situations, check out my examples [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases&highlight=).

Answer (score 0):

solved now

```
    conn.Open()

    query = "SELECT count(total_telat) as total_telat FROM kkpsurabaya WHERE total_telat <=30 and total_telat >=1"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
    Try

        RD = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If RD.Read() Then
            Label7.Text = RD.GetValue(0)
        End If
        RD.Close()
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
```

Comment: Better but still not the best.  See my other answer.